# Zod Array of Object Schema with Shadcn component on ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, forms, schema, zod

Hi I have a formSchema and all of them are object like this and I am trying to add an Array of Objects:

```
const formSchema = z.object({
  reviewer: z.object({
    reviewerName: z.string({
      required_error: 'Please select a reviewer\'s Name to display.',
    }),
    reviewerEmail: z.string({
      required_error: 'Please select a reviewer\'s Email to display.',
    }),
    reviewerPassword: z.string({
      required_error: 'Please select a reviewer\'s Password to display.',
    }),
  }),
  developer: z.object({
    developerName: z.string({
      required_error: 'Please select a developer\'s Name to display.',
    }),
    developerEmail: z.string({
      required_error: 'Please select a developer\'s Email to display.',
    }),
    developerPassword: z.string({
      required_error: 'Please select a developer\'s Password to display.',
    }),
  }),
  project: z.object({
    projectName: z.string({
      required_error: 'Please select a project\'s Name to display.',
    }),
  })
});
```

Additional schema:

```
,
  checklist: z.array(z.object({
    name: z.string({
      required_error: 'Please enter a checklist name.',
    }),
    description: z.string({
      required_error: 'Please enter a checklist description.',
    }),
    isCompleted: z.boolean({
      required_error: 'Please specify if the checklist is completed.',
    }),
  })),
```

If I add a checklist schema, I cant map it on my form with shadcn component, how can I properly map an Array of object inside my form here because I am planning to have a array of object of checklists:

```
    <Card>
    <CardHeader>
      <CardTitle>Add Review</CardTitle>
      <CardDescription>Add Review to a Project</CardDescription>
    </CardHeader>
    <CardContent>
            <Form {...form}>
        <form className="space-y-8" onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          {Object.entries(formSchema.shape).map(([parentKey, parentValue]) =>
            Object.entries(parentValue.shape).map(([key]) => {
                                const fieldName: string = `${parentKey}.${key}`;
                                const field: FieldName = fieldName as FieldName;
              return (
                <FormField
                  key={field}
                  control={form.control}
                  name={field}
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <FormItem>
                      <FormLabel>{key}</FormLabel>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Input
                          placeholder={key}
                          {...field}
                          value={getNestedFieldValue(form.getValues(), fieldName) || ''}
                        />
                      </FormControl>
                      <FormMessage />
                    </FormItem>
                  )}
                />
              );
            })
          )}
          <div className="flex justify-between">
            <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </Form>
    </CardContent>
  </Card>
```